# C# - why is this program giving me an error?

Tags: c#

I am practicing for my programming exam and that's one of the exams. This program crashes after the first for loop and I can't figure out why. Please help!

```
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{0}", new string('-', n / 2), new string('*', n + 2));

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}*{0}", new string('-', n / 2), new string('-', n));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}{1}{2}{1){0}",
            new string('-', ((n - 1) / 2) - i),
            new string('*', 1 + 2 * i),
            new string('-', n - 2 * i));

        if (i < n / 2)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Without an error message, I have to downvote for total lack of quality/effort.

Comment: when input is double numbers like 4,6, what is you want to print?

Comment: It  will always be an odd number.

Answer (score 3):

```
"{0}{1}{2}{1){0}",
```

Your string format is error,you need to change your `{1)` to `{1}`,but it seems the code never end while input is 5! and other input also take another exception,can you explain what you want to do ?

```
"{0}{1}{2}{1}{0}",
```

I changed your code to a method now

```
static void PrintDemo(int num)
{
    if (num < 0 || num % 2 == 0)
    {
        return;//do nothing
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{0}", new string('-', num / 2), new string('*', num + 2));

    for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}*{0}", new string('-', num / 2), new string('-', num));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        var t1 = Math.Abs(num / 2 - i);
        var t2 = t1 * 2 + 1;
        var t3 = (num * 2 + 1 - t1 * 2 - t2) / 2;
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}{1}{2}{1}{0}",
            new string('-', t1),
            new string('*', t3),
            new string('-', t2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats like my second post here. Sorry about the question being awful. I ran to some problems with posting the code.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I still don't see what they are talking about... :/

Comment: @Loocid Oh, I see the difference, take a look at the bracket at {1) Sky changed to {1}

Comment: @Loocid Its *really* hard to spot, but look at the braces around the second "1"

Comment: @Sky Fang Please add a little explanation to your answer

Comment: I saw it, thanks. Thank god .. what a mistake.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/48d96df697373ab1dd3b78a9f52d0e0c This is what I am trying to make.

Comment: `PrintDemo` worked as your wish

Answer (score 1):

The first error has been answered by [Sky Fang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420159/1387827) 
After that you will get ArgumentOutOfRangeException. For this you will have to change your second forloop condition to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < (n-1)/2; i++)
{
 ....
}
```

This is because when you are printing this is one of your arguments

```
new string('-', ((n - 1) / 2) - i)
```

Your second argument is becoming negative as i increases to (n-1)/2

**Edit**
Here is the final code. Adding Console.Readline will keep the console up and will enable you to see the output

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{0}", new string('-', n / 2), new string('*', n + 2));

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}*{0}", new string('-', n / 2), new string('-', n));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1) / 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "{0}{1}{2}{1}{0}",
                new string('-', ((n - 1) / 2) - i),
                new string('*', 1 + 2 * i),
                new string('-', n - 2 * i));

            if (i < n / 2)
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: When I do that, the code never ends ?

Comment: If you fix the Format exception and the loop, the program should end.
Here is the output I see
http://screencast.com/t/ZoITD3sBII

Comment: Can you post all of the code ?